# Error in output of function to search for files in directory C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, search, vector, directory

I have built this function to search for files in a certain directory.

Everything works well, but when I am printing the vectors, the output of vectors is wrong. Inside the while loop, the vectors are filled with the right data, but when I output them outside of the while loop (in the next for loop), the data is not the same anymore.

I cannot figure out what is wrong. Any idea?

```
void search(const fs::path& directory, const fs::path& file_name, string input, string &compFileName, string &Fpath)
{
    string t;
    auto d = fs::recursive_directory_iterator(directory);
    auto found = std::find_if(d, end(d), [&](const auto & dir_entry)
    {
        Fpath = dir_entry.path().string();
        t = dir_entry.path().filename().string();
        return t.find(file_name.string()) != std::string::npos;
    }
    );

    if (found == end(d))
        cout << "File was not found" << endl;
    else
    {
        int count = 0;
        vector<LPCSTR> pfilesFound; //path
        vector<LPCSTR> nfilesFound; //name

        while (found != end(d))
        {
            count++;
            LPCSTR cFpath = Fpath.c_str();//get path and insert it in the shellexecute function
            LPCSTR ct = t.c_str();
            pfilesFound.push_back(cFpath);
            nfilesFound.push_back(ct);

            d++;
            found = std::find_if(d, end(d), [&](const auto & dir_entry)
            {
                Fpath = dir_entry.path().string();
                t = dir_entry.path().filename().string();
                return t.find(file_name.string()) != std::string::npos;
            });
        }

        cout << "We found the following items" << endl;
        int count2 = 0;
        for (std::vector<LPCSTR>::const_iterator i = nfilesFound.begin(); i != nfilesFound.end(); ++i)
        {
            count2++;
            std::cout << count2 << "- " << *i << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Read about what you're storing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230350.aspx)

Comment: MS typedefs... Pointers are pointers, whether named `LPCSTR` or `const char*`.

Answer (score 1):

```
LPCSTR cFpath = Fpath.c_str();
```

This is not creating a copy of `FPath`, it just gives the pointer to raw memory where the actual string is stored.

```
Fpath = dir_entry.path().string();
```

Now `Fpath` has different value, and so does the internal raw memory and the pointer that you stored is pointing to different value now.

When `t.find(file_name.string()) != std::string::npos;` is hit, `Fpath` is modified here as well which would be referred by all stored pointers in vector.

Answer (score 1):

You are storing pointers to string buffer that get invalidated every time you change the source string. So both vectors are basically filled with dangling pointers. You need to store strings instead like this:  `vector<::std::string> pfilesFound;`.